# Re-rendering when enter data into input fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new into React-Native and I have some problems with my code.
When I am trying to enter something to my TextInput or DateInput, I've got render 4 times
the same data. I tried using memo but then it still render twice so I am unable to use this components because when I am entering 'abcdfg' it loses focus on 'a' and renders.

My main purpose is to make one object from three different tabs and then send it to server. Maybe I am doing it wrong.

Thanks in advance :)

I have Modal Component like this :

```
interface NewDreamModalProps {
  showModal: boolean;
  dream?: DreamModel;
  toggle: (show: boolean) => void;
}
export function NewDreamModal(props: NewDreamModalProps) {
  const [navigationState, setNavigationState] = useState({
    index: 0,
    routes: [
      {key: 'description', title: 'Opis'},
      {key: 'analysis', title: 'Analiza'},
      {key: 'consciousness', title: 'Świadomość'},
    ],
  });
  const [newDream, setNewDream] = useState<Partial<DreamModel>>({});
  console.log('new dream,', newDream);
  function addDream() {
    instance
      .post('/dream', {
        firstName: 'Fred',
        lastName: 'Flintstone',
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={false}
        visible={props.showModal}>
        <TabView
          navigationState={navigationState}
          renderScene={SceneMap({
            description: () => (
              <DreamDescription dream={newDream} setNewDream={setNewDream} />
            ),
            analysis: AnalysisModal,
            consciousness: ConsciousnessModal,
          })}
          onIndexChange={(index: number) =>
            setNavigationState({...navigationState, index})
          }
          initialLayout={{width: Dimensions.get('window').width}}
        />
        <View style={styles.buttonsContainer}>
          <Button
            style={styles.buttonNav}
            mode="contained"
            onPress={() => {
              if (navigationState.index === 0) {
                props.toggle(!props.showModal);
              } else {
                setNavigationState({
                  ...navigationState,
                  index: navigationState.index - 1,
                });
              }
            }}>
            {navigationState.index === 0 ? 'Wyjdź' : 'Wróć'}
          </Button>
          <Button
            style={styles.buttonNav}
            mode="contained"
            onPress={() => {
              if (navigationState.index === 2) {
                props.toggle(!props.showModal);
              } else {
                setNavigationState({
                  ...navigationState,
                  index: navigationState.index + 1,
                });
              }
            }}>
            {navigationState.index === 2 ? 'Zapisz' : 'Dalej'}
          </Button>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

I am updating 'newDream' from child component named DreamDescription

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import TextInput from './TextInput';
import DatePicker from 'react-native-date-picker';
import {IconButton, Paragraph} from 'react-native-paper';
import {theme} from '../core/theme';
import moment from 'moment';
import RNPickerSelect, {Item} from 'react-native-picker-select';
import {instance} from '../api/axios';
import {mapStringsToItems} from '../api/helpers/mappings';
import {DreamModel} from '../models/dream';

interface DreamDescriptionProps {
  dream: Partial<DreamModel>;
  setNewDream: (dream: Partial<DreamModel>) => void;
}

export function DreamDescription(props: DreamDescriptionProps) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [open2, setOpen2] = useState(false);
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState<Array<Item>>([]);
  function getCategories() {
    instance
      .get('categories')
      .then(function (response) {
        setCategories(
          mapStringsToItems(
            response.data.docs.map((item: {name: any}) => item.name),
          ),
        );
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getCategories();
    return () => {
      setCategories([]);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.scene}>
      <TextInput
        label="Tytuł"
        returnKeyType="next"
        value={props.dream.title}
        onChangeText={(text: string) =>
          props.setNewDream({...props.dream, title: text})
        }
        autoCapitalize="none"
        autoFocus
      />
      <View style={styles.dateIcons}>
        <Paragraph>Czas zaśnięcia </Paragraph>
        <Paragraph>
          {moment(props.dream.startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')}
        </Paragraph>
        <IconButton
          onPress={() => setOpen(true)}
          icon="calendar"
          size={30}
          color={theme.colors.primary}
        />
      </View>

      <View style={styles.dateIcons}>
        <Paragraph>Czas obudzenia</Paragraph>
        <Paragraph>
          {moment(props.dream.endDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')}
        </Paragraph>
        <IconButton
          onPress={() => setOpen2(true)}
          icon="calendar"
          size={30}
          color={theme.colors.primary}
        />
      </View>

      <TextInput
        label="Treść"
        returnKeyType="next"
        value={props.dream.description}
        onChangeText={(text: string) =>
          props.setNewDream({...props.dream, description: text})
        }
        autoCapitalize="none"
        multiline={true}
        numberOfLines={10}
        errorText={undefined}
        description={undefined}
      />
      <RNPickerSelect
        key={props.dream.category?.name}
        placeholder={{value: 'Wybierz kategorie'}}
        value={props.dream.category?.name}
        onValueChange={() => null}
        items={categories}
      />
      <DatePicker
        modal
        open={open}
        date={props.dream.startDate || new Date()}
        androidVariant="iosClone"
        title="Sen rozpoczął się.."
        textColor={theme.colors.primary}
        locale={'pl'}
        confirmText="Zatwierdź"
        cancelText="Anuluj"
        is24hourSource="locale"
        onConfirm={date => {
          setOpen(false);
          props.setNewDream({...props.dream, startDate: date});
        }}
        onCancel={() => {
          setOpen(false);
        }}
      />
      <DatePicker
        modal
        open={open2}
        date={props.dream.endDate || new Date()}
        androidVariant="iosClone"
        title="Sen zakończył się.."
        textColor={theme.colors.primary}
        locale={'pl'}
        confirmText="Zatwierdź"
        cancelText="Anuluj"
        is24hourSource="locale"
        onConfirm={date => {
          setOpen2(false);
          props.setNewDream({...props.dream, endDate: date});
        }}
        onCancel={() => {
          setOpen2(false);
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scene: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    padding: 30,
  },
  dateIcons: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    alignContent: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
});
```

Comment: why you use return under useEffect function? Lo

Comment: to cleanup but this return doesnt affect to my problem